# How to represent EOT in local time?

Tags: .net, timezone, nodatime

I have some NodaTime code that is looking at zone intervals:

```cs
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Phoenix"];
var interval = zone.GetZoneInterval(SystemClock.Instance.Now);
Console.WriteLine(interval.End);
Console.WriteLine(interval.IsoLocalEnd);
```

`interval.End` outputs `EOT`, which is expected since this zone does not use daylight savings time.  But I cannot output the `interval.IsoLocalEnd` value.  It throws an exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Value should be in range [-27255-31195]
Parameter name: year
Actual value was 31197.
  Source=NodaTime
  ParamName=year
  StackTrace:
       at NodaTime.Utility.Preconditions.CheckArgumentRange(String paramName, Int32 value, Int32 minInclusive, Int32 maxInclusive)
       at NodaTime.Calendars.BasicCalendarSystem.GetYearTicks(Int32 year)
       at NodaTime.Calendars.GregorianCalendarSystem.GetYearTicks(Int32 year)
       at NodaTime.Calendars.BasicGJCalendarSystem.GetMonthOfYear(LocalInstant localInstant, Int32 year)
       at NodaTime.Calendars.BasicCalendarSystem.GetMonthOfYear(LocalInstant localInstant)
       at NodaTime.Fields.BasicMonthOfYearDateTimeField.GetValue(LocalInstant localInstant)
       at NodaTime.LocalDateTime.get_Month()
       at NodaTime.Text.LocalDateTimePatternParser.<.cctor>b__8(LocalDateTime value)
       at NodaTime.Text.Patterns.DatePatternHelper.<>c__DisplayClassd`2.<>c__DisplayClass10.<CreateMonthOfYearHandler>b__c(TResult value, StringBuilder sb)
       at NodaTime.NodaAction`2.Invoke(TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2)
       at NodaTime.Text.Patterns.SteppedPatternBuilder`2.SteppedPattern.Format(TResult value)
       at NodaTime.Text.Patterns.PatternBclSupport`1.Format(T value, String patternText, NodaFormatInfo formatInfo)
       at NodaTime.LocalDateTime.ToString(String patternText, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
       at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(Object value)
       at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(Object value)
```

Is this a bug? Or is this expected behavior and I should check `interval.End == Instant.MaxValue` before trying to use the `interval.IsoLocalEnd` value?

I am using NodaTime 1.1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, Noda Time has some issues with converting instants to local dates at points close to (or at) the end of time. See e.g. [issue 197](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=197) and [issue 113](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=113). This appears to be another occurrence of the same kind of problem.

I'd suggest filing a bug. One suggestion, though: check whether you see the same results with Noda Time 1.0: the fix for issue 197 (in 1.1.0) could conceivably have caused this as a regression.

Comment: It's worse than that, of course - `Instant.MaxValue` is meant to be "EOT", but you can subtract a single tick from it to get an instant which is a very definite instant on the time line. In an ideal world we'd probably want something closer to IEEE-754, where infinity stays infinite. It's definitely one of the weaker aspects of Noda Time.